# Cant retrieve discounted product price in custom script

Tags: magento

I have a custom script that outputs a list of particular products in csv format. The frontend of the store just runs fine, however when retrieving the price of a product in my script, the actual FinalPrice does not take my catalog price rules into account, which is kind of messed up, since the `getFinalPrice()` method works perfectly in template files ect..

This is my code, which I have drastically shortened for demonstration purposes:

```
<?php   
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');

    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(27809);

    echo $product->getFinalPrice();
?>
```

This outputs the product's regular price, but not the price accounted for the catalog price rule. I have just applied all catalog rules again and have also rebuilt all indexes. As I said, the discount prices show fine in the frontend, but for some reason I am not able to retrieve them in my script.

I hope someone has an idea what could be going wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product final price is calculated in an observer, and your script is not loading the events configuration.

See my addition below.

```
<?php   
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');

    //load event configuration areas
    Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(27809);

    echo $product->getFinalPrice();
?>
```

See `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::processFrontFinalPrice();`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is not quite working yet: both prices that are being output by "getPrice" and "getFinal" methods have changed, but are still wrong now and roughly 5% below what they should be. Do you have any more hints?

Comment: Is the difference to do with tax?

Comment: Please post the data. A `$product->debug()` dump should do the trick.

Comment: Now, this is embarassing: Ben's solution worked perfectly, I had a typo in my product id. Thanks a lot!!