# Events in Frontend in Config.xml

Tags: xml, events, magento, configuration, scope

In config.xml, `<events>` can be placed in either `<global>`, `<frontend>` or `<adminhtml>`.  We are bootstraping Magento, and because we are bootstrapping, the events that I have in `<frontend>` do not fire.   What tells magento to use the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ben gave a response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829771/336905) that covers exactly this question. Basically, you need to instruct Magento to load an "Area" so that it knows what configuration elements (including events) to implement.  When you hit a page managed by Magento, this is executed automatically for you in `Mage::app()->run()`.