# Retrieve discounted price for a specific store

Tags: magento

In my Magento site, catalog price rules are different depending on the store.
Specifically, a same product with the same base price will have a different final discounted price according to the store.

I would like to retrieve all different final discounted prices for a same product.
After several unsuccessful approaches (basically, all the other answers on SO that did not call *app()->loadAreaPart*), the closest I get so far is being able to retrieve the final price in the main store only (Id=1), using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8829771/3805717):

```
<?php   
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

//load event configuration areas
Mage::app()->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(27809);

echo $product->getFinalPrice();
?>
```

However, I did not manage to retrieve the price for Store Id=2
I tried the two following approaches without success:

```
1) $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->SetStroreId(2)->load(27809);
```

This one returns the final price in Store Id=1

```
2) Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($current_store_id);
   $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(27809);
```

This on returns the price without discount.

Answer (score 0):

You should create different group and set up them per store as `Default Group`
`System - Configuration - Customer Configuration - Create New Account Options`
after that you can set up price per group for product.
I hope this solves your problem

Comment: I do not need to set up the discounted price, but read it programmatically. So I am sorry if I do not understand how your suggestion could help me towards this goal.